# Why does the header of the tab shows the first tag and not the title of the question?

Tags: discussion, title

Why does the header of the tab shows the first tag and not the title of the question as other stackexchange sites?

Comment: Iirc, the header is of the form `[first tag]: title - …`, unless the first tag name is already in the title, in which case the `[tag] -` is skipped.

Comment: @muru Ok so why this question doesn't have the [tag] in the header while `discussion` is not in the title?

Comment: Presumably because it's a required tag on meta sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's done to boost the Google ranking of Stack Exchange pages. It's been the case [since 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71906/first-tag-in-the-title-of-the-page-is-not-that-convenient). Google's ranking algorithms have changed quite a lot, I don't know if there's been any reevaluation of whether this is still relevant.

It happens on all Stack Exchange sites, not just this one. But it doesn't happen for every question: if all the tags of the question are already a word in the title, no tag is added. Also this isn't done on meta, presumably because Google ranking of meta posts isn't important.

If it annoys you, you can [remove it via a browser extension](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71951/remove-the-most-popular-tag-from-the-title-using-javascript). That's what I do.